# File uploads using CURLFile fails in PHP7.4

Tags: php, file-upload, php-curl, php-7.4

I query an API to which I upload files but no files are uploaded when I post using PHP7.4, however, it works fine with PHP7.3.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
   public function upload($opts = array())
   {
        $files = array();

        foreach($opts['files'] as $i => $file)
        {
                $files['files[' . $i . ']'] = new CURLFile($file);
        }

        unset($opts['files']);

        $data = array_merge($files, array( "data" => json_encode($opts)));
        $response = self::curlRequest( "https://api.example.com/", $data);

        return $response;
    }

    public static function curlRequest($url, $data)
    {
                $curl = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);

                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);


        return $response;

   }
```

So the upload function accepts a multidimensional array of values including an array of files with index 'files'. It iterates through the files, creating CURLFile objects then posts these along with the rest of the data to the API.

Using PHP7.4, the global variables $_REQUEST and $_FILES on the API server are always empty. With PHP7.3 these variables are populated with the sent data as expected.

On https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php it states:

> CURLFile now supports stream wrappers in addition to plain file names, if the extension has been built against libcurl >= 7.56.0.

Libcurl version is 7.58.

A related bug report has been submitted here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79013 regarding the Content-Length header missing resulting in no file uploads but it seems the PHP team thinks the problem is with the server, not PHP.

Does anyone has any idea how to upload files using PHP7.4?

Comment: Waiting for PHP 7.4.4 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version PHP 7.4.4 fixed this issue. Seems it was indeed a bug.